# Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, Arrhenius equation and activation energy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry

If I have a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, will the number of molecules $N_a$ that have energy higher than $E_a$ be equal to $N_0 e^{−E_a/KT}$, where $N_0$ is the total number of molecules?

**EDIT:** This seems to be suggested by many references (see, for instance [this](http://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Kinetics/Modeling_Reaction_Kinetics/Collision_Theory/The_Collision_Model_of_Chemical_Kinetics)) dealing with Arrhenius equation, but I do not see why $N_a$ shouldn't  just be the integral of Maxwell-Bolztmann between $E_a$ and $\infty$.

What is the relationship between Arrhenius equation and the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Close!

The number of molecules with an energy higher than $E_a$ will be

$$N_0 \sqrt{\left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_B T}\right)^3}4\pi\int_{E_a}^{\infty}v^2e^{\Large{\frac{-mv^2}{2k_BT}}}dv$$

Remember, the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution is a probability distribution of particle speeds in an ideal gas. Like any probability distribution which gives the probability of observing $x$, which is just $\displaystyle{\frac{N(x)}{N_0}}$, you have to integrate from $x$ to $\infty$ to find the probability of observing $x$ and greater. To find the number with $x$ and greater, just multiply that result by $N_0$, the known number of constituents.

Comment: Why does this link then seem to suggest something different? http://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Kinetics/Modeling_Reaction_Kinetics/Collision_Theory/The_Collision_Model_of_Chemical_Kinetics

Comment: I mean at the section "Arrhenius Equation"

Comment: I dealt with this question a long time ago but I've forgotten how I learned that the answer to your question is no. I'm looking further into it to refresh my memory but I can tell you that it's not as straightforward as  I think you are thinking.